# URI rewrite issue in tomcat7 + angularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have the issue of rewrite URL in tomcat.

Worked Well

1. I implemented the location html5mode in y angular app, using the refer:

   // use the HTML5 History API

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

And in the index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

and some changes in the Gruntfile.js, It worked great and I could see the clean URL in the address bar,
ex:http://demoApp/#/hichanged to http://demoApp/hi
But

2. When I moved the code base to the apache tomcat machine( staging server), I realized that we need to change some configurations, and I followed the 
   http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

for installing/enabling the mod_rewrite, but the same is not working in the staging server, when I type the URl as 
http://demoApp/#/hi OR http://demoApp/hi

The page displays like

[image]

I feel need to change some thing in here

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/#/*</url-pattern> <!-- NOT SURE, WHAT TYPE OF PATTERN SHOULD GO HERE  -->
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Actually I am not much sure about tomcat,

So guys here please help me in fixing this, please let me know if you need more details

Comment: Check http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#install / urlrewrite.xml for the rules.

Comment: @Giannis, Thanks for the comment, but as you can see, in my question, I have the same set of steps http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ , Are you sure, there is a difference in your reference link

Comment: I figured out how to do this without a library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43922919/1236092